# SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO when setting up ssl

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

I am using the guide [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL) here to try to setup ssl for our Jetty 8 instance(s) but getting the following errors:

```
curl https://localhost/service/health
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

My jetty-ssl.xml is below.

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <!-- if NIO is not available, use org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector -->

  <New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl.SslContextFactory">
    <Set name="KeyStore"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/etc/keystore</Set>
    <Set name="KeyStorePassword">PASSWORD</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStore"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/etc/keystore</Set>
    <Set name="TrustStorePassword">PASSWORD</Set>
  </New>

  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
        <Arg><Ref id="sslContextFactory" /></Arg>
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="Port">443</Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
        <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
        <Set name="AcceptQueueSize">100</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

To loaded the certs I using.

```
keytool -keystore keystore -import -alias jetty -file public.pem
```

My cert file looks like [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/usmanismail/c30b9a5cf4dd2f94b45c/raw/34ba01a28b2fba05304fdeb9031b2741c688f3b6/public.pem).

An I am running this inside a docker/ubuntu:14.04 container if that makes any difference.

Any ideas on what I am missing from for configuration?

Comment: Any errors on the server side?  What kind of certificates?  How did you build your keystore?  Did you configure the connector's certs in any way?

Comment: No errors on the server side, even the request logs don't seem to see the https requests. I did not change any setting in the connector from default jetty-ssl other than port (8443 to 443). I have updated the question with the keystore command I used. thx